# Post-hoc t-test in R

Tags: r, anova, posthoc, t-test

I did a between subjects repeated measurement ANOVA in R, giving me the same results as SPSS.

The design is the following: Positivity (2 Levels) x Recency (2 Levels) x Group (3 Levels)

As a result I have a three-way interaction. Now, I want to do all possible post-hoc t-tests, separately for the three groups. This is feasible with the following code and using the lsmeans and the afex packages:

```
anova_all <- aov_ez("code", "err", stim.lng, +
within=.("recency", "positivity"), between=.("group"))
ref <- lsmeans(anova_all,~recency*positivity|group)
comps <- contrast(ref,method="pairwise", adjust="none")
summary(comps)
```

The code runs, but I get different results compared to the SPSS output (in terms of p-values and t-values). This confuses me and I believe I should get similar results as in SPSS, since only paired-sample t-tests are carried out.

I guess the crucial point might be the different degrees of freedom in both softwares. For instance, when I carry out a paired t-test in specific group of 9 subjects, in SPSS the degrees of freedom is 9 whereas it is between 89-102 in R (see attached images). Why is this so high in R? Is there any other of replicating the results of SPSS with R?

Here my design and the three different outputs from SPSS and R in a specific group of patients for all possible pairwise post-hoc tests:

Output from R:

[image]

Output from SPSS:

[image]

Comment: It seems like a structural issue within either your code or your SPSS design, because the standard estimates are matching, but the degrees of freedom are definitely different.

Comment: I note you say that "only paired-sample t-tests are carried out". Maybe that's what SPSS is doing, but it is decidedly not what's done fitting the model `anova_all` that you show. That model is based on an assumption of homogeneous error variances, whereby all "between" variations have the same variance and all the "within" errors have the same variance. With such an underlying assumption, those common variances are estimated by pooling together the variations that SPSS is apparently estimating separately -- resulting in much larger d.f.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I guess @rvl hit the point. So, if I have a three-way interaction and want to clarify it, I don't want my variances to be pooled together as the model in R does right? I would think that I want to compare two conditions and estimate the variances separately, as SPSS does. **bold** Does anyone have an idea if there is package, with which this can be implemented in R (separate estimation of variance in post-hoc paired-sample t-tests)?

Comment: To the contrary, you gain a lot of power and get a more parsimonious model by pooling variances. So as long as the model fits the data (look st diagnostic plots) it is a good idea. I'd be surprised if SPSS doesn't offer some other modeling choices, but I don't use it so I don't know.

Comment: @rvl: Thank you for your comment! I get the overall idea of pooling varinaces to gain power, but in this setting it does not make sense to me. Assuming I have an interaction of group A and B, means to me, that effects in both groups go in different directions. So then I would look at both groups individually, exploring how the effects are in group A and then in group B. Therefore, lets say I explore group A, now pooling together the variance in this group with that of group B feels very odd for me. Because, I want to know what in A is different to be. Is there somehow a wrong twist in my head?

Comment: The effects due to your factors may go in different directions, but the random variations around those effects are independent of them. The programs that fit the models sort out all that stuff and pool the random variations together.